# Create or Update Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in my Nodejs project and I found a problem that I'm having a hard time to solve.
Basically I have a cron that gets an array of objects from a server than inserts it on my database as a object ( for this case, cartoons ). But if I already have one of the objects, I have to update it.

Basically I have a array of objects and a could use the BulkCreate() method. But as the Cron starts again, it doesn't solve it so I was needing some sort of update with an upsert true flag. And the main issue: I must have a callback that fires just once after all these creates or updates. Does anyone have an idea of how can I do that? Iterate over an array of object.. creating or updating it and then getting a single callback after?

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 112, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#creating-persistent-instances), you don't need to query `where` to perform the update once you have the object. Also, the use of promise should simplify callbacks:

**Implementation**

```
function upsert(values, condition) {
    return Model
        .findOne({ where: condition })
        .then(function(obj) {
            // update
            if(obj)
                return obj.update(values);
            // insert
            return Model.create(values);
        })
}
```

**Usage**

```
upsert({ first_name: 'Taku' }, { id: 1234 }).then(function(result){
    res.status(200).send({success: true});
});
```

**Note**

1. This operation is not atomic.
2. Creates 2 network calls.

which means it is advisable to re-think the approach and probably just update values in one network call and either:

1. Look at the value returned (i.e. rows_affected) and decide what to do.
2. Return success if update operation succeeds. This is because whether the resource exists is not within this service's responsibility.

Comment: return Model.create({...values, ...condition})

Comment: When working with high frequency data, not being atomic causes repetition of data to happen! Otherwise, an elegant solution!

Answer (score 31):

You can use [upsert](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert)
It's way easier.

> Implementation details:
>
> - MySQL - Implemented as a single query `INSERT values ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE values`
> - PostgreSQL - Implemented as a temporary function with exception handling: `INSERT EXCEPTION WHEN unique_constraint UPDATE`
> - SQLite - Implemented as two queries `INSERT; UPDATE`. This means that the update is executed regardless of whether the row already
>     existed or not
> - MSSQL - Implemented as a single query using `MERGE and WHEN (NOT) MATCHED THEN` **Note** that SQLite returns undefined for created, no
>     matter if the row was created or updated. This is because SQLite
>     always runs `INSERT OR IGNORE + UPDATE`, in a single query, so there
>     is no way to know whether the row was inserted or not.

Comment: Use upsert, but if it performed an insert, you'll then need to then get the inserted object :( - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29071422/48348

Comment: @IanGrainger - not anymore!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301416/107277

Comment: The link is broken the current API documentation for `upsert`: https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-upsert

Answer (score 25):

**Update 07/2019** now with async/await

```
async function updateOrCreate (model, where, newItem) {
    // First try to find the record
   const foundItem = await model.findOne({where});
   if (!foundItem) {
        // Item not found, create a new one
        const item = await model.create(newItem)
        return  {item, created: true};
    }
    // Found an item, update it
    const item = await model.update(newItem, {where});
    return {item, created: false};
}
```

I liked the idea of Ataik, but made it a little shorter:

```
function updateOrCreate (model, where, newItem) {
    // First try to find the record
    return model
    .findOne({where: where})
    .then(function (foundItem) {
        if (!foundItem) {
            // Item not found, create a new one
            return model
                .create(newItem)
                .then(function (item) { return  {item: item, created: true}; })
        }
         // Found an item, update it
        return model
            .update(newItem, {where: where})
            .then(function (item) { return {item: item, created: false} }) ;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
updateOrCreate(models.NewsItem, {slug: 'sometitle1'}, {title: 'Hello World'})
    .then(function(result) {
        result.item;  // the model
        result.created; // bool, if a new item was created.
    });
```

Optional: add error handling here, but I strongly recommend to chain all promises of one request and have one error handler at the end.

```
updateOrCreate(models.NewsItem, {slug: 'sometitle1'}, {title: 'Hello World'})
    .then(..)
    .catch(function(err){});
```

Comment: Comment: I noticed taht update() .. does not return the database object. So if you need it you may fetch it one more time.

Answer (score 12):

This might be an old question, but this is what I did:

```
var updateOrCreate = function (model, where, newItem, onCreate, onUpdate, onError) {
    // First try to find the record
    model.findOne({where: where}).then(function (foundItem) {
        if (!foundItem) {
            // Item not found, create a new one
            model.create(newItem)
                .then(onCreate)
                .catch(onError);
        } else {
            // Found an item, update it
            model.update(newItem, {where: where})
                .then(onUpdate)
                .catch(onError);
            ;
        }
    }).catch(onError);
}
updateOrCreate(
    models.NewsItem, {title: 'sometitle1'}, {title: 'sometitle'},
    function () {
        console.log('created');
    },
    function () {
        console.log('updated');
    },
    console.log);
```

Comment: Hint: Use promise chaining for error handling and save 50% of your code :)

Comment: how to use it for parent child relationship? how to upsert child table?

Answer (score 11):

```
User.upsert({ a: 'a', b: 'b', username: 'john' })
```

It will try to find record by hash in 1st param to update it, if it will not find it - then new record will be created

[Here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/test/integration/model/upsert.test.js#L64) is example of usage in sequelize tests

```
it('works with upsert on id', function() {
    return this.User.upsert({ id: 42, username: 'john' }).then(created => {
        if (dialect === 'sqlite') {
            expect(created).to.be.undefined;
        } else {
            expect(created).to.be.ok;
        }

        this.clock.tick(1000);
        return this.User.upsert({ id: 42, username: 'doe' });
    }).then(created => {
        if (dialect === 'sqlite') {
            expect(created).to.be.undefined;
        } else {
            expect(created).not.to.be.ok;
        }

        return this.User.findByPk(42);
    }).then(user => {
        expect(user.createdAt).to.be.ok;
        expect(user.username).to.equal('doe');
        expect(user.updatedAt).to.be.afterTime(user.createdAt);
    });
});
```

Comment: It will find a match on a unique or primary key column

Comment: I really liked the way answered the question. Kudos

Answer (score 2):

Sound likes you want to wrap your Sequelize calls inside of an [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each).

Comment: I was hoping for some upset option on the Update from Sequelize but it seems out of the road map. I'll try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the custom event emitter.

Assuming your data is in a variable called data.

```
new Sequelize.Utils.CustomEventEmitter(function(emitter) {
    if(data.id){
        Model.update(data, {id: data.id })
        .success(function(){
            emitter.emit('success', data.id );
        }).error(function(error){
            emitter.emit('error', error );
        });
    } else {
        Model.build(data).save().success(function(d){
            emitter.emit('success', d.id );
        }).error(function(error){
            emitter.emit('error', error );
        });
    }
}).success(function(data_id){
    // Your callback stuff here
}).error(function(error){
   // error stuff here
}).run();  // kick off the queries
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `findOrCreate` and then `update` methods in sequelize. here is a sample with async.js

```
async.auto({
   getInstance : function(cb) {
      Model.findOrCreate({
        attribute : value,
        ...
      }).complete(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          cb(null, false);
        } else {
          cb(null, result);
        }
      });
    },
    updateInstance : ['getInstance', function(cb, result) {
      if (!result || !result.getInstance) {
        cb(null, false);
      } else {
        result.getInstance.updateAttributes({
           attribute : value,
           ...
        }, ['attribute', ...]).complete(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            cb(null, false);
          } else {
            cb(null, result);
          }
        });
       }
      }]
     }, function(err, allResults) {
       if (err || !allResults || !allResults.updateInstance) {
         // job not done
       } else {
         // job done
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**2022 update:**

You can use the `upsert` function:

[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-upsert](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-upsert)

Insert or update a single row. An update will be executed if a row which matches the supplied values on either the primary key or a unique key is found. Note that the unique index must be defined in your sequelize model and not just in the table. Otherwise you may experience a unique constraint violation, because sequelize fails to identify the row that should be updated.

**Implementation details:**

`MySQL` - Implemented with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

`PostgreSQL` - Implemented with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE. If update data contains PK field, then PK is selected as the default conflict key.
Otherwise first unique constraint/index will be selected, which can satisfy conflict key requirements.

`SQLite` - Implemented with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE

`MSSQL` - Implemented as a single query using MERGE and WHEN (NOT) MATCHED THEN
Note that Postgres/SQLite returns null for created, no matter if the row was created or updated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that either updates deviceID -> pushToken mapping or creates it:

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var PushToken = require("../models").PushToken;

var createOrUpdatePushToken = function (deviceID, pushToken) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    PushToken
      .findOrCreate({
        where: {
          deviceID: deviceID
        }, defaults: {
          pushToken: pushToken
        }
      })
      .spread(function (foundOrCreatedPushToken, created) {
        if (created) {
          fulfill(foundOrCreatedPushToken);
        } else {
          foundOrCreatedPushToken
            .update({
              pushToken: pushToken
            })
            .then(function (updatedPushToken) {
              fulfill(updatedPushToken);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              reject(err);
            });
        }
      });
  });
};
```