# How to get the ID of an inserted or updated record in Sequelize upsert?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i need to get the id for the inserted/updated record when using `.upsert()` in sequelize.

right now `.upsert()` returns a boolean indicating whether the row was created or updated.

```
return db.VenueAddress.upsert({
            addressId:address.addressId,
            venueId: venue.venueId,
            street: address.street,
            zipCode: address.zipCode,
            venueAddressDeletedAt: null
        }).then(function(test){
            //test returned here as true or false how can i get the inserted id here so i can insert data in other tables using this new id?
        });
```

Comment: as you need a unique id to do an upsert, and have to provide a value for that id, you have it already

Comment: No, because I insert a new record and then I want the autoincrement id of that record

Answer (score 38):

I don't think that returning the upserted record was available when the OP asked this question, but it has since been implemented with this [PR](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/8924). As of **Sequelize v4.32.1**, you can pass a boolean `returning` as a query param to select between returning an array with the record and a boolean, or just a boolean indicating whether or not a new record was created.

You do still need to provide the id of the record you want to **upsert** or a new record will be created.

For example:

```
const [record, created] = await Model.upsert(
  { id: 1, name: 'foo' }, // Record to upsert
  { returning: true }     // Return upserted record
);
```

Comment: As of May 2019, this is not supported for MySQL.

Comment: @max_i Is there a different method now?

Comment: upsert still not supporting MySQL @cullanrocks you can implement your own based on Matthew Chung mentioned.

Comment: As of 6.14.0, this does not work for SQLite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72092277/895245 Also now `returning: true` is the default, no need to pass it explicitly: https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-upsert

Answer (score 11):

I wanted upsert to return the created or updated object. It doesn't because only PGSQL supports it directly, apparently.

So I created a naive implementation that will - probably in a non-performant way, and possibly with all sorts of race conditions, do that:

```
Sequelize.Model.prototype.findCreateUpdate = function(findWhereMap, newValuesMap) {
  return this.findOrCreate({
    where: findWhereMap, 
    defaults: findWhereMap
  })
  .spread(function(newObj, created) {
    // set:
    for(var key in newValuesMap) {
      newObj[key] = newValuesMap[key];
    }

    return newObj.save();
  });
};
```

Usage when trying to create/update a move in a game (contrived example alert!):

```
models.Game
.findOne({where: {gameId: gameId}})
.then(function(game) {
  return db.Move.findCreateUpdate(
    {gameId: gameId, moveNum: game.moveNum+1}, 
    {startPos: 'kr4', endPos: 'Kp2'}
  );
});
```

Comment: this was really helpful for me creating my own `findAndUpdateOrCreate` function :-)

Comment: SQLite [added RETURNING](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) (the Postgres feature that enables it to work there) in 3.35.0 (2021)  so hopefully just a matter of time until someone implements it there: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12426

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me:

```
Model.upsert({
    title:your title,
    desc:your description,
    location:your locations
}).then(function (test) {
    if(test){
        res.status(200);
        res.send("Successfully stored");
    }else{
        res.status(200);
        res.send("Successfully inserted");
    }
})
```

It will check db to find based on your primary key. If it finds then, it will update the data otherwise it will create a new row/insert into a new row.

Comment: I think you misread the question for this - OP wanted to get the id of the record that was created or updated from running the upsert query, which is impossible to immediately get for all dialects at this point in time (with the exception of Postgres and MSSQL) since in your example - 'test' will be a boolean.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3354#issuecomment-139470795

Answer (score 7):

i know this is an old post, but in case this helps anyone

```
const upsert = async (model: any, values: any, condition: any): Promise<any> => {
  const obj = await model.findOne({ where: condition })
  if (obj) {
    // only do update is value is different from queried object from db
    for (var key in values) {
      const val = values[key]
      if (parseFloat(obj[key]) !== val) {
        obj.isUpdatedRecord = true
        return obj.update(values)
      }
    }
    obj.isUpdatedRecord = false
    return obj

  } else {
    // insert
    const merged = { ...values, ...condition }
    return model.create(merged)
  }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  I made some changes to the check if the update needed to happen with JSON.stringify()

`
                const val = JSON.stringify(values[key]);
                const updateVal = JSON.stringify(obj[key]);

                if (updateVal !== val) {
                    await obj.update(values).then((data) => {
                        toCheckAfterSql = data;
                        data.isUpdatedRecord = true;
                    }).catch(err => {
                        throw new Error(err);
                    });
                }
`

Answer (score 6):

It isn't using upsert, but [`.bulkCreate`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate) has an `updateOnDuplicate` parameter, which allows you to update certain fields (instead of creating a new row) in the event that the primary key already exists.

```
MyModel.bulkCreate(
  newRows,
  {
    updateOnDuplicate: ["venueId", ...]
  }
)
```

I believe this returns the resulting objects, and so I think this might enable the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: On sequelize 6.14.0 sqlite3 5.0.2 this does do upsert (`ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`), but returns wrong ID values, presumably because RETURNING was only added recently to SQLite: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12426

Answer (score 3):

janmeier said:

This is only supported by postgres, so to keep the API consistent across dialects this is not possible.

please see : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3354

Comment: Note: This is getting implemented. See [PR #6325](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/6325).

Comment: @MaxTruxa any idea when? I personally would love to have the feature inside Sequelize, even if the code internally is: 'insert or update and return object'. (I assume that findCreateFind doesn't do what I need as I'm assuming that the defaults are *only* set on create, and won't do an update).

Comment: @Ian Grainger I have no idea. I'm not involved in the project, just found the PR. You could ask one of the maintainers/the creator of the PR.

Answer (score 1):

I believe my solution is the most up to date with most minimal coding.

```
const SequelizeModel = require('sequelize/lib/model')
SequelizeModel.upsert = function() {
  return this.findOne({
    where: arguments[0].where
  }).then(obj => {
    if(obj) {
      obj.update(arguments[0].defaults)
      return
    }
    return this.create(arguments[0].defaults)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in case this helps anyone...you can get the returned id or any other value in this way based on OP data.

```
   var data = {
    addressId:address.addressId,
    venueId: venue.venueId,
    street: address.street,
    zipCode: address.zipCode,
    venueAddressDeletedAt: null
   }

   const result = await db.VenueAddress.upsert(data, { returning: true });
   console.log('resulttttttttttttttttt =>', result)
   
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Your success message', data: result[0].id});
```

Noticed how I passed `{ returning: true }` and get the value from the result data.

Comment: Sequelize code comments on 'returning' attribute say it is "only for postgres."

Answer (score 0):

Super old, but if it helps someone:

```
const [city, created] = await City.upsert({
  id: 5,
  cityName: "Glasgow",
  population: 99999,
});
```

`created` is the boolean saying whether the item was created, and in `city` you have the whole item, where you can get your id.

No need of `returning`, and this is db agnostic :)

Comment: OP likely wants ID as an autoincremented field, not explicitly given in INSERT. For that use case, sequelize 6.14.0 sqlite3 5.0.2 returns wrong IDs, presumably because RETURNING was only implemented in 2021 in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

**The only solution for SQLite in Sequelize 6.14.0 is to query the inserted row again**

I haven't found a solution that works besides a new SELECT query.

It does work in PostgreSQL however.

Presumably, this is because `RETURNING` was only implemented relatively recently in SQLite 3.35.0 from 2021: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html and Sequelize doesn't use that version yet.

I've tried both:

- `Model.upsert` with `returning: true`: did not work on SQLite. BTW, as mentioned at: [https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-upsert](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-upsert) `returning` already defaults to `true` now, so you don't need to pass it explicitly
- `Model.bulkCreate` with `updatOnDuplicate`

In both of those cases, some dummy value is returned when the object is present, not the one that is actually modified.

Minimal runnable examples from https://cirosantilli.com/sequelize

update_on_duplicate.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path')
const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
let sequelize
if (process.argv[2] === 'p') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
  })
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'tmp.sqlite',
  })
}
function assertEqual(rows, rowsExpect) {
  assert.strictEqual(rows.length, rowsExpect.length)
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = rows[i]
    let rowExpect = rowsExpect[i]
    for (let key in rowExpect) {
      assert.strictEqual(row[key], rowExpect[key])
    }
  }
}
;(async () => {
const Integer = sequelize.define('Integer',
  {
    value: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      unique: true, // mandatory
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    inverse: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
await Integer.sync({ force: true })
await Integer.create({ value: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'   });
await Integer.create({ value: 3, inverse: -3, name: 'three' });
await Integer.create({ value: 5, inverse: -5, name: 'five'  });
let rows

// Initial state.
rows = await Integer.findAll({ order: [['id', 'ASC']]})
assertEqual(rows, [
  { id: 1, value: 2, name: 'two',   inverse: -2 },
  { id: 2, value: 3, name: 'three', inverse: -3 },
  { id: 3, value: 5, name: 'five',  inverse: -5 },
])

// Update.
rows = await Integer.bulkCreate(
  [
    { value: 2, name: 'TWO'   },
    { value: 3, name: 'THREE' },
    { value: 7, name: 'SEVEN' },
  ],
  { updateOnDuplicate: ["name"] }
)
// PostgreSQL runs the desired:
//
// INSERT INTO "Integers" ("id","value","name") VALUES (DEFAULT,2,'TWO'),(DEFAULT,3,'THREE'),(DEFAULT,7,'SEVEN') ON CONFLICT ("value") DO UPDATE SET "name"=EXCLUDED."name" RETURNING "id","value","name","inverse";
//
// but "sequelize": "6.14.0" "sqlite3": "5.0.2" does not use the desired RETURNING which was only added in 3.35.0 2021: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html
//
// INSERT INTO `Integers` (`id`,`value`,`name`) VALUES (NULL,2,'TWO'),(NULL,3,'THREE'),(NULL,7,'SEVEN') ON CONFLICT (`value`) DO UPDATE SET `name`=EXCLUDED.`name`;
//
// so not sure how it returns any IDs at all, is it just incrementing them manually? In any case, those IDs are
// all wrong as they don't match the final database state, Likely RETURNING will be added at some point.
//
// * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063232/sequelize-upsert
// * https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7478
// * https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12426
// * https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3354
if (sequelize.options.dialect === 'postgres') {
  assertEqual(rows, [
    { id: 1, value: 2, name: 'TWO',   inverse: -2 },
    { id: 2, value: 3, name: 'THREE', inverse: -3 },
    // The 6 here seems to be because the new TWO and THREE initially take up dummy rows,
    // but are finally restored to final values.
    { id: 6, value: 7, name: 'SEVEN',  inverse: null },
  ])
} else {
  assertEqual(rows, [
    // These IDs are just completely wrong as mentioned at: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12426
    // Will be fixed when one day they use RETURNING.
    { id: 4, value: 2, name: 'TWO',   inverse: undefined },
    { id: 5, value: 3, name: 'THREE', inverse: undefined },
    { id: 6, value: 7, name: 'SEVEN', inverse: undefined },
  ])
}

// Final state.
rows = await Integer.findAll({ order: [['id', 'ASC']]})
assertEqual(rows, [
  { id: 1, value: 2, name: 'TWO',    inverse: -2 },
  { id: 2, value: 3, name: 'THREE',  inverse: -3 },
  { id: 3, value: 5, name: 'five',   inverse: -5 },
  { id: 6, value: 7, name: 'SEVEN',  inverse: null },
])

})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() });
```

upsert.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path')
const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
let sequelize
if (process.argv[2] === 'p') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
  })
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'tmp.sqlite',
  })
}
function assertEqual(rows, rowsExpect) {
  assert.strictEqual(rows.length, rowsExpect.length)
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let row = rows[i]
    let rowExpect = rowsExpect[i]
    for (let key in rowExpect) {
      assert.strictEqual(row[key], rowExpect[key])
    }
  }
}
;(async () => {
const Integer = sequelize.define('Integer',
  {
    value: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      unique: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    inverse: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
await Integer.sync({ force: true })
await Integer.create({ value: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'   });
await Integer.create({ value: 3, inverse: -3, name: 'three' });
await Integer.create({ value: 5, inverse: -5, name: 'five'  });
let rows

// Initial state.
rows = await Integer.findAll({ order: [['id', 'ASC']]})
assertEqual(rows, [
  { id: 1, value: 2, name: 'two',   inverse: -2 },
  { id: 2, value: 3, name: 'three', inverse: -3 },
  { id: 3, value: 5, name: 'five',  inverse: -5 },
])

// Update.
rows = [(await Integer.upsert({ value: 2, name: 'TWO' }))[0]]
if (sequelize.options.dialect === 'postgres') {
  assertEqual(rows, [
    { id: 1, value: 2, name: 'TWO', inverse: -2 },
  ])
} else {
  // Unexpected ID returned due to the lack of RETURNING, we wanted it to be 1.
  assertEqual(rows, [
    { id: 3, value: 2, name: 'TWO', inverse: undefined },
  ])
}
rows = [(await Integer.upsert({ value: 3, name: 'THREE' }))[0]]
if (sequelize.options.dialect === 'postgres') {
  assertEqual(rows, [
    { id: 2, value: 3, name: 'THREE', inverse: -3 },
  ])
} else {
  assertEqual(rows, [
    { id: 3, value: 3, name: 'THREE', inverse: undefined },
  ])
}
rows = [(await Integer.upsert({ value: 7, name: 'SEVEN' }))[0]]
if (sequelize.options.dialect === 'postgres') {
  assertEqual(rows, [
    { id: 6, value: 7, name: 'SEVEN',  inverse: null },
  ])
} else {
  assertEqual(rows, [
    { id: 6, value: 7, name: 'SEVEN', inverse: undefined },
  ])
}

// Final state.
rows = await Integer.findAll({ order: [['value', 'ASC']]})
assertEqual(rows, [
  { id: 1, value: 2, name: 'TWO',    inverse: -2 },
  { id: 2, value: 3, name: 'THREE',  inverse: -3 },
  { id: 3, value: 5, name: 'five',   inverse: -5 },
  { id: 6, value: 7, name: 'SEVEN',  inverse: null },
])

})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() });
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.14.0",
    "sql-formatter": "4.0.2",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

In both of those examples, we see that PostgreSQL runs the desired:

```
INSERT INTO "Integers" ("id","value","name") VALUES (DEFAULT,2,'TWO'),(DEFAULT,3,'THREE'),(DEFAULT,7,'SEVEN') ON CONFLICT ("value") DO UPDATE SET "name"=EXCLUDED."name" RETURNING "id","value","name","inverse";
```

which works due to `RETURNING`, but sequelize does not use the desired RETURNING

```
INSERT INTO `Integers` (`id`,`value`,`name`) VALUES (NULL,2,'TWO'),(NULL,3,'THREE'),(NULL,7,'SEVEN') ON CONFLICT (`value`) DO UPDATE SET `name`=EXCLUDED.`name`;
```

Tested on Ubuntu 21.10, PostgreSQL 13.5.

Answer (score -1):

Which I myself resolved as follows:

```
return db.VenueAddress.upsert({
        addressId:address.addressId,
        venueId: venue.venueId,
        street: address.street,
        zipCode: address.zipCode,
        venueAddressDeletedAt: null
    },{individualHooks: true}).then(function(test){ 
        // note individualHooks
    });
```

Comment: If you want to emit hooks for each individual record, along with the bulk hooks you can pass  individualHooks: true to the call.

Model.destroy({ where: {accessLevel: 0}, individualHooks: true})
// Will select all records that are about to be deleted and emit before- + after- Destroy on each instance

Model.update({username: 'Toni'}, { where: {accessLevel: 0}, individualHooks: true})
// Will select all records that are about to be updated and emit before- + after- Update on each instance

Comment: afterupsert hook returns "create" variable (true/false), not the object instance. So the id is not obtained from here